# Integrating CCAvenue using NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ccavenue

I am a total newbie to payment gateways. I would like to integrate CCAvenue to my web application using NodeJS. I have installed the CCAvenue package from npm, but I don't have any idea about doing payment.

I would be great if anyone pointed to me to a tutorial other then the CCAvenue integration manual.

Comment: Did u get any success in integrating ccavenue with angularjs?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would like to suggest using integration kit for nodejs which is provided by CCAvenue (non-seamless)

1) Add the dataForm from integration kit in your UI component as it is

2) Call the rest api using ajax as follows:

```
app.controller("changeProfileController", function($scope, $sce){
  var dataObject = $("#paymentDataForm").serializeArray();
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: restApiServer.ReSTFulAPIHost + '/ccavRequestHandler',
      data: dataObject,
      cache : false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (res) {
        //console.log(data);
        $scope.myText = $sce.trustAsHtml(res.data);
      },
      dataType: 'json'
  });
});
```

3) Call ccAvenueRequestHandler code from Integration kit which will generate html form as follows

```
// Use your own credentials
var workingKey = "AECGKJBBSERVFBG";
var accessCode = "ab4512vhvweb56g784433";
// formObject is data send from client
var contentArray = [];
_.each(formObject, function(value, key, data){
     contentArray.push(key+"="+data[key]);
});
body = contentArray.join("&");
encRequest = ccav.encrypt(body,workingKey);
var formBody = '<form id="nonseamless" method="post" name="redirect" action="https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction"  ><input type="text" name="access_code" id="access_code" value="'+ accessCode +'" style="display:none;" ><input type="text" id="encRequest" name="encRequest" value="'+ encRequest +'" style="display:none;" ><script language="javascript">document.redirect.submit();</script></form>';
return reply(formBody);
```

4) As Angularjs don't provide direct route to another url. You have to create one DOM in UI where you can render html form in response (2), which will redirect to ccavenue payment page

```
// HTML Code
<div ng-bind-html='myText'></div>
```

5) Add ccavenueResponse handler from kit to handle your response, Decrypt the data from ccavenue and redirect your user to link which contain the response data

```
var workingKey = "AECGKJBBSERVFBG", //Put in the 32-Bit key shared by CCAvenues.
ccavResponse = ccav.decrypt(request.payload.encResp,workingKey);
var strArray = ccavResponse.split("&");
var resObject =  {};
for(var i=0; i< strArray.length; i++){
  var tempArray = strArray[i].split("=");
  resObject[tempArray[0]] = tempArray[1]; 
}
// resObject will contains the payment information
// You can use this data as you want
```

Comment: Once the HTML has been rendered in the div on success response, will the redirect take place automatically? If yes, what exactly in code tells the form to do so? If no, How can I make it a yes without user intervention?

Comment: Redirection take place automatically because the html form that you generated contains the post method and auto submit script.. see "formBody".

Comment: I'm integrating with CCAvenue as well. Just one question: can we "submit" form data directly to CCAvenue from a Node process?

Comment: Yes you can ... You have to enable Cors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ccavenue` npm package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ccavenue